# Dropdown default value Power Apps

Tags: powerapp

trying to set up a dropdown default value.
The value originates from sharepoint list entry.

tried this formula, but  does not work.

LookUp('UKI_Rolling Stock list1_2', Title = "N/A")

Can any one help?
Thanks a million

Comment: hi Jose. Does `LookUp('UKI_Rolling Stock list1_2', Title = "N/A")` return any values? What if you output `LookUp('UKI_Rolling Stock list1_2', Title = "N/A")` in a label?

Comment: Denis, it does not return any values.
Very strange, because N/A is on my data source

Comment: Can you output `UKI_Rolling Stock list1_2` to a table or a gallery as another test? It's also possible that the N/A is spelled with a space or a special character in SharePoint.

Comment: Dear Denis, The issue was on the delegation.
'N/A' value was on row 569. I had the delegation set to 500.
Thanks a million for your advice. i did use your guidance with the table and I was bale to see values :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue relied on the App delegation setting.
"N/A" value was on row 569.
Delegation setting was set at 500. hence I could not see it.
Changed delegation value to 1000. I am able to see all values.
Hope this helps others.

Regards

Jose